# What is the difference between Informix `%iY` and `%Y` format

Tags: informix

I found in some code I maintain they used this format for an update query

```
UPDATE X=to_date('$var','%iY-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%F3') ...
```

But I can't find anywhere in Informix documentation what the `i` is for. Running this next query will result the same values.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%F3')  as wo_I, 
       TO_CHAR(CURRENT, '%iY-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%F3') as with_I FROM X; 

wo_i                    | with_i
------------------------|------------------------
2017-06-20 16:49:44.712 | 2017-06-20 16:49:44.712
```

So what am I missing?

Resources I looked into:

1. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_130.htm
2. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_129.htm
3. http://www.sqlines.com/informix-to-oracle/to_char_datetime

Answer (score 4):

It's a trifle hard to find, but one location for the information you need (assuming you use Informix 11.70 rather than 12.10, though it probably hasn't changed much) is:

- [Client APIs and Tools — GLS User's Guide — GLS Environment Variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_079.htm#ids_gug_079)

In particular, it says:

- `%iy` — Is replaced by the year as a two-digit number (00 - 99) for both reading and printing. It is the formatting directive specific to IBM Informix for `%y`.
- `%iY` — Is replaced by the year as a four-digit number (0000 - 9999) for both reading and printing. It is the formatting directive specific to IBM Informix for `%Y`.
- …
- `%y` — Requires that the year is a two-digit number (00 through 99) for both reading and printing.
- `%Y` — Requires that the year is a four-digit number (0000 through 9999) for both reading and printing.

There clearly isn't much difference between the two — I'm not even sure I understand what the difference is supposed to be.  I think it may be the difference between accepting but not requiring leading zeros on 1, 2 or 3 digit year numbers.  But for the most part, it seems you can treat them as equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for find this, I was hoping for a clear answer, I also emailed to Informix support about this, still didn't got any answer from them.